# PHP PDO resulting in no data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm currently using php 5.3 in combination with mysql server 5.1.61.
I'm currently trying to do a loginscript, but I'm running into the problem
that I'm getting no result data and no error message.
The function that handles the login is the following:

```
 public function doLogin($username,$pw)
    {
        $db=new incdb();
        $row['name']=':username';
        $row['value']=$username;
        $row['type']=PDO::PARAM_STR;
        $parameters[]=$row;
        $row['name'] = ':password';
        $row['value'] = $pw;
        $row['type'] = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        $parameters[] = $row;
        $query=$db->execSql('SELECT * FROM tbUser WHERE '
                        .'username=:username AND password=MD5(:password)',$parameters);
        unset($parameters);
        unset($db);
        $data=$query->fetch();
        if (isset($data) && is_array($data))
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=$data['id'];
            $_SESSION['loggedInData']=$data;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'error';
            return 0;
        }
}
```

The incdb class has the execSql function as follows:

```
    public function execSql($sql, $parameters)
{
    $query=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($parameters as $param)
    {
        $query->bindParam($param['name'], $param['value'], $param['type']);
    }
    $query->execute();

    return $query;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? (I'm relatively new to using php PDO....in the past I always used the mysql functions directly). Tnx

Comment: Have you tried replacing `bindParam` with `bindValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot bind a parameter as a argument of a function.

Change your code like this:

```
$row['name'] = ':password';
$row['value'] = MD5($pw);
$row['type'] = PDO::PARAM_STR;
```

And your querty like this:

```
$query=$db->execSql(
  'SELECT * FROM tbUser WHERE '
   .'username=:username AND password=:password', $parameters);
```

Keep in mind that depending on the character set of the database the username comparison can be case sensitive!

Comment: Tnx after moving the md5 to the $row['value'] it functioned. 
Although another thing I just found out through that....the md5 generated by that mysql version and php 5.3 seems different (had to manually put the php md5 value into the db because of that).
In total functions with moving md5 to the php part tnx again

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the wrong parameter, you are passing an array with an array in the position 0. You only have to pass one associative array with the values. E.g.

```
array('username' => 'mjuarez')
```